# Reading User control property inside Nested Master pages in Content page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a user control which is in the root master page. The content page connects to this root master page via nested master page

root.master>apps.master>content.aspx

the user control in the root.master has a drop downlist that sets a property when the dropdownlist selection is changed.

I need to access this user control property in the content page.

any help is appreciated

user control property

```
 private string _userCurrentCity = string.Empty;


    public string userCurrentCity
    {

        get { return _userCurrentCity; }

        set { _userCurrentCity = value; }

    }

 protected void ddl_City_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string CurrentCity = "";

        CurrentCity = ddl_City.SelectedItem.Text;
        lbl_CurrentCity.Text = CurrentCity;
        HiddenField_CityID.Value = ddl_City.SelectedValue;
        UpdatePanel2.Update();

        userCurrentCity = CurrentCity;//this sets the usercontrol property
    }
```

in my content page

```
  UserControl cnt = this.Master.Master.FindControl("Change1") as UserControl;            


  lbl_Result.Text = cnt.userCurrentCity;
```

is this correct, i set the userCurrentCity property in the ddl selected change event. Your code looks logical but it is not working.

Comment: please show some code what you tried

Answer (score 0):

You need some code like this in code behind:

```
UserControl cnt = this.Master.FindControl("IDOfTheUserControl") as UserControl
```

after that:

```
cnt.Property //to access the wanted property.
```

EDIT: **I don't understand yhat you have nested master pages.**

Try `this.Master.Master.FindControl` and other things like before.

```
UserControl cnt = this.Master.Master.FindControl("IDOfTheUserControl") as UserControl
```

Comment: This did not work, as the user control is in parent master page. when i use this code it will access the child master pge.

Comment: @carrieat check my edit I don't understand that you have nested master pages.

Comment: code added in the first post, your code looks logical but it is not working

Comment: @carrieat use debug and see after this is code is written if the control is in cnt variable. If this is true, that means that the property is not fill with correct information and you should check it.

Comment: Error 9 does not contain a definition for 'cnt' and no extension method 'cnt' accepting a first argument of type '####' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: UserControl cnt = this.Master.FindControl("IDOfTheUserControl") as UserControl do you have any problem on this line of code ? When you pu the correct values for the user control ?

Comment: i don't get any problem in this line, But only when accessing it string currentcity = cnt.userCurrentCity

Comment: @carrieat you are not using the property right this is another problem :) Post some code in the question. How you set the property how you define it and where you are using the FindControl

Comment: @carrieat use debug and see, everything look ok.